# How to retrieve the second value of an array after comparing the first value of array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to retrieve the description of holiday if the given date of period time exist in table.

So, I have a table naming tbl_holiday.

```
holiday_id  holiday_date    holiday_desc        
1   4/18/2019   Maundy Thursday 
2   4/19/2019   Good Friday     
3   4/20/2019   Black Friday
```

My script:

```
$s = $conn->prepare(SELECT holiday_date, holiday_desc FROM tbl_holiday);
$s->execute();
$res = $s->get_result();
$holiday_res = array();
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc())
{
$holiday_res[] = $row;
}
```

Also, I have a block of code to retrieve within the period of time

```
$from = new DateTime($_GET['from']);
$to = new DateTime($_GET['to']);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$from->setTime(0, 0);
$to->setTime(0, 0)->add($interval);
$period = new DatePeriod($from, $interval, $to);

foreach ($period as $dt) 
{
 $date = $dt->format("m/d/Y");
}
```

Comment: Do the holiday date unique?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the second block of code, you can just use mysql to query the period window that you want.

**This example is not secure, have a look at mysql injections!**

Also make sure that the date format from the php file and from the database matches

Below I am assuming that `$from` and `$to` is in the same date format as the database

```
 $from = $_GET['from'];
 $to = $_GET['to'];
 $s = $conn->prepare(SELECT holiday_date, holiday_desc FROM tbl_holiday 
 WHERE holiday_date >= '$from' AND holiday_date <= '$to');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push all range to array and then check if database holiday_date comes in that range of from and to,

```
/**
 * For getting period
 */
$fDate    = $_GET['from'];
$tDate    = $_GET['to'];
$from     = new DateTime($fDate);
$to       = new DateTime($tDate);
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$from->setTime(0, 0);
$to->setTime(0, 0)->add($interval);
$period = new DatePeriod($from, $interval, $to);
$temp = [];
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $temp[] = $dt->format("m/d/Y");
}
$result = [];
/**
 * Looping through holiday data
 */
foreach ($holiday_res as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value['holiday_date'], $temp)){ // checking if holiday comes in range
        $result[] = $value; // if yes then put it in result
    }
}
// $result is what you are looking for
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to rewrite this line

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc())
```

as

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
```